# Transaction Error. Exception thrown in contract code. (MetaMask)

Tags: metamask, error

When I use Ganache it runs with no problem and MetaMask too. When I run my contract in my private Ethereum network (Geth). When I use a function from my contract the MetaMask gives me this error (title).

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

contract Creation {

    int basiclife = 50;

    struct hero {
        string name;
        int life;
        int lvl;
        int xp;
        int attack;
        int winCount;
        int trophies;
        int lossCount;
    }

    hero[] public heroes; 

    struct enemy {  
        string name;
        int life;
        int lvl;
        int xp;
        int attack;
    }

    enemy[] public enemies;
    mapping (uint => address) public herotoowner;
    mapping (address => uint) public heroCount;
    mapping (uint => address) public monstertoowner;
    uint public monsterCount; 

    function createhero (string memory _name) public {
        require(heroCount[msg.sender] == 0);
        uint id= heroes.push(hero(_name, basiclife, 1, 0, 20, 0, 0, 0))-1;
        herotoowner[id] = msg.sender;
        heroCount[msg.sender]++;
    }

    function enemyRage (int _herolvl) public {
        uint id = enemies.push(enemy("Rage", 20*_herolvl, _herolvl, 7*_herolvl, 5*_herolvl)) - 1;
        monstertoowner[id] = msg.sender;
        monsterCount++;
    }

    function enemyDerpina (int _herolvl) public {
        uint id = enemies.push(enemy("Derpina", 40*_herolvl, _herolvl, 14*_herolvl, 10*_herolvl)) - 1; 
        monstertoowner[id] = msg.sender;
        monsterCount++;
    }

    function getHerosByOwner (address owner) external view returns (uint) {
        uint result = 999999;
        for (uint i = 0; i < heroes.length; i++) {
            if (herotoowner[i] == owner) {
                result = i;
                break;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    function getmonstersByOwner (address owner) external view returns (uint) {
        uint result = 0;
        for (uint i = enemies.length; i > 0; i--) {
            if (monstertoowner[i] == owner) {
                result = i;
                break;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    uint nonce=0;

    function randNum (int _num) private returns (int) {  //sinartisi gia tixaies times
        int randomnumber = int(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(now, msg.sender, nonce))) % _num;
        if (randomnumber <= 0) {
            randomnumber = (-1)*randomnumber;
        }
        nonce++;
        return randomnumber;
    }

    function attack_hero (uint _heroid, uint _monsterid, int _num) external returns (string memory, int, int, int, int ) {
        hero storage myhero = heroes[_heroid];
        enemy storage monster = enemies[_monsterid];
        int attackofhero = 0;
        if(_num == 0) { 
            attackofhero = randNum(myhero.attack);
        }

        monster.life = monster.life - attackofhero;
        int attackofmonster = randNum(monster.attack);
        myhero.life = myhero.life - attackofmonster;

        if (monster.life <= 0 && myhero.life > 0) {
            myhero.winCount++;
            myhero.xp += monster.xp;
            if (randNum(100) > 50 ){ 
                myhero.trophies++;
            }
            return("win", myhero.lvl, myhero.xp, myhero.life, myhero.trophies);
        }

        if (myhero.xp >= 10+2*myhero.lvl){ 
            myhero.lvl++;
            myhero.xp = 0; //reset you xp
            myhero.life = basiclife*myhero.lvl;  
            myhero.attack = myhero.attack*myhero.lvl;
        }

        if (myhero.life <= 0 ) { //ita 
            myhero.lossCount++; 
            return("dead", myhero.lossCount, myhero.life, myhero.lvl, myhero.trophies);
        }
        return("attack", myhero.life, attackofhero, monster.life, attackofmonster);
    }

    function resurrection (uint _heroid) public { 
        hero storage myhero = heroes[_heroid];
        myhero.life = basiclife*myhero.lvl;
    }
}
```

I add my app.ss code too

```
App = {
    web3Provider: null,
    contracts: {},
    account: '0x0',
    heros: [],
    enemies: [],
    heroId: null,
    monsterId: null,
    rand: null,
    rand2: 0,
    init: function() {

        return App.initWeb3();

    },

    initWeb3: function() {
        // TODO: refactor conditional
        if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
            // If a web3 instance is already provided by Meta Mask.
            App.web3Provider = web3.currentProvider;
            web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
        } else {
            // Specify default instance if no web3 instance provided
            App.web3Provider = new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('localhost:8545');
            web3 = new Web3(App.web3Provider);
        }
        return App.initContract();
    },

    initContract: function() {
        $.getJSON("Creation.json", function(Creation) {
            // Instantiate a new truffle contract from the artifact
            App.contracts.Creation = TruffleContract(Creation);
            // Connect provider to interact with contract
            App.contracts.Creation.setProvider(App.web3Provider);

            return App.render();
        });
    },
    monsterRender: function() {
        var enemyspot = $("#enemyspot");
        enemyspot.empty();
        if (App.rand == 1) {
            App.contracts.Creation.deployed().then(function(instance) {
                creationInstance = instance;
                return creationInstance.getmonstersByOwner(App.account);
            }).then(function(getmonstersByOwner) {
                App.monsterId = getmonstersByOwner;
                console.log(App.monsterId)
                return creationInstance.enemies(getmonstersByOwner)
            }).then(function(enemies) {
                console.log("hey 1" + enemies)
                App.enemies[App.monsterId] = enemies;
                var name = enemies[0];
                var life = enemies[1];
                var lvl = enemies[2];
                var xp = enemies[3];
                var atk = enemies[4];

                var enemyTemplate = "<tr ><td colspan='2'><img src = './images/rage.jpg' width ='200px'></td></tr><tr><td> Name</td><td>: " + name + "</td></tr><tr><td>Health Points</td><td>: " + life + " HP</td></tr><tr><td>Level</td><td>: " + lvl + "</td></tr><tr><td>Experiance</td><td>: " + xp + "</td></tr><tr><td>Attack</td><td>: " + atk;
                enemyspot.append(enemyTemplate);

            }).then(function() {
                if (App.enemies[App.monsterId][1] <= 0) {
                    alert("You have won!!!");

                    enemyspot.empty();
                }
            });
        } else {
            App.contracts.Creation.deployed().then(function(instance) {
                creationInstance = instance;

                return creationInstance.getmonstersByOwner(App.account);
            }).then(function(getmonstersByOwner) {
                App.monsterId = getmonstersByOwner;
                return creationInstance.enemies(getmonstersByOwner)
            }).then(function(enemies) {
                console.log("hey 1" + enemies)

                App.enemies[App.monsterId] = enemies;
                var name = enemies[0];
                var life = enemies[1];
                var lvl = enemies[2];
                var xp = enemies[3];
                var atk = enemies[4];

                var enemyTemplate = "<tr ><td colspan='2'><img src = './images/derpina.jpg' width ='200px'></td></tr><tr><td> Name</td><td>: " + name + "</td></tr><tr><td>Health Points</td><td>: " + life + " HP</td></tr><tr><td>Level</td><td>: " + lvl + "</td></tr><tr><td>Experiance</td><td>: " + xp + "</td></tr><tr><td>Attack</td><td>: " + atk;
                enemyspot.append(enemyTemplate);
            }).then(function() {
                if (App.enemies[App.monsterId][1] <= 0) {
                    alert("You have won!!!");
                    isCreated =0;
                    var enemyspot = $("#enemyspot");
                    enemyspot.empty();
                }
            });
        }
    },


    render: function() {

        // Load account data
        web3.eth.getCoinbase(function(err, account) {
            if (err === null) {
                App.account = account;
                $("#accountAddress").html("Your Account: " + account);
            }
        });
        var herospot = $("#herospot");
        herospot.empty();
        // Load contract data
        App.contracts.Creation.deployed().then(function(instance) {
            creationInstance = instance;
            return creationInstance.getHerosByOwner(App.account);
        }).then(function(getHerosByOwner) {
            console.log("hey äóáä" + getHerosByOwner)
            App.heroId = getHerosByOwner;
            console.log(App.heroId)
            return creationInstance.heroes(getHerosByOwner);
        }).then(function(heroes) {
            $("#charform").hide();
            $("#story").hide();
            console.log(account)
            App.heroes = heroes;

            var name = heroes[0];
            var life = heroes[1];
            var lvl = heroes[2];
            var xp = heroes[3];
            var atk = heroes[4];
            var winCount = heroes[5];
            var trophies = heroes[6];
            var lossCount = heroes[7];
            var heroTemplate = "<tr ><td colspan='2'><img src = './images/happyfa.jpg' width ='200px'></td></tr><tr><td> Name</td><td>: " +
                name + "</td></tr><tr><td>Health Points</td><td>: " + life + " HP</td></tr><tr><td>Level</td><td>: " +
                lvl + "</td></tr><tr><td>Experiance</td><td>: " + xp + "</td></tr><tr><td>Attack</td><td>: " + atk + "</td></tr><tr><td>Win count</td><td>: " + winCount +
                "</td></tr><tr><td>trophies</td><td>: " + trophies + "</td></tr><tr><td>lossCount</td><td>: " + lossCount;
            herospot.append(heroTemplate);
        }).then(function() {
            console.log("hello"+App.heroes[1])
            if (App.heroes[1] <= 0) {
                console.log("sdasd" + App.heroes[1])
                alert("You have Lost!!!");
                var enemyspot = $("#enemyspot");
                enemyspot.empty();
                App.resurrection();
                isCreated =0;
            }
        }).then(App.loadMonsters());
    },
    fight: function() {
        App.contracts.Creation.deployed().then(function(instance){
            creationInstance = instance;
            return creationInstance.attack_hero(App.heroId, App.monsterId, App.rand2);
        }).then(function(attack_hero){
            App.monsterRender();
    App.render();
     App.rand2 = 0;
        })
    },
    resurrection:function() {

             App.contracts.Creation.deployed().then(function(instance){
            creationInstance = instance;
                return creationInstance.resurrection(App.heroId);
            }).then(function(resurrection){
                App.render();
            });
    },
/*
    heroSlap: function() {
        App.contracts.Creation.deployed().then(function(instance) {
            creationInstance = instance;
            return creationInstance.attack_hero(App.heroId, App.monsterId);
        }).then(function(attack_hero) {
            console.log(attack_hero)
        }).then(function(){
             console.log("h zwh tou teratos einai" +App.enemies[App.monsterId][1])
             if (App.enemies[App.monsterId][1] > 0) {
           App.monsterSlap();

        }  else if(App.enemies[App.monsterId][1] <= 0){
            isCreated =0;
            console.log("einai "+ isCreated)
        }
         App.monsterRender();
    });
    },
    monsterSlap: function() {
        App.contracts.Creation.deployed().then(function(instance) {
            creationInstance = instance;
            return creationInstance.attack_monster(App.heroId, App.monsterId);
        }).then(function(attack_monster) {
            App.render();


        })
    },
*/

    spawn: function() {
        console.log(App.heroes)
        console.log(App.account)
        var rand = Math.round(Math.random() * 1);
        App.rand = rand;
        var enemyspot = $("#enemyspot");
        enemyspot.empty();
        if (rand == 1) {
            App.contracts.Creation.deployed().then(function(instance) {
                creationInstance = instance;
                return creationInstance.enemyRage(App.heroes[2]);
            }).then(function(enemyRage) {
                console.log("hey1 " + enemyRage)
                return creationInstance.getmonstersByOwner(App.account);
            }).then(function(getmonstersByOwner) {
                App.monsterId = getmonstersByOwner;

                return creationInstance.enemies(getmonstersByOwner)
            }).then(function(enemies) {
                console.log("hey 1" + enemies)
                App.enemies.push(enemies);
                App.enemies[App.monsterId] = enemies;
                var name = enemies[0];
                var life = enemies[1];
                var lvl = enemies[2];
                var xp = enemies[3];
                var atk = enemies[4];

                var enemyTemplate = "<tr ><td colspan='2'><img src = './images/rage.jpg' width ='200px'></td></tr><tr><td> Name</td><td>: " + name + "</td></tr><tr><td>Health Points</td><td>: " + life + " HP</td></tr><tr><td>Level</td><td>: " + lvl + "</td></tr><tr><td>Experiance</td><td>: " + xp + "</td></tr><tr><td>Attack</td><td>: " + atk;
                enemyspot.append(enemyTemplate);
                isCreated = 1;
            });
        } else {
            App.contracts.Creation.deployed().then(function(instance) {
                creationInstance = instance;
                return creationInstance.enemyDerpina(App.heroes[2]);
            }).then(function(enemyDerpina) {
                console.log("hey1 " + enemyDerpina)
                return creationInstance.getmonstersByOwner(App.account);
            }).then(function(getmonstersByOwner) {
                App.monsterId = getmonstersByOwner;
                return creationInstance.enemies(getmonstersByOwner)
            }).then(function(enemies) {
                console.log("hey 1" + enemies)
                App.enemies.push(enemies);
                App.enemies[App.monsterId] = enemies;
                var name = enemies[0];
                var life = enemies[1];
                var lvl = enemies[2];
                var xp = enemies[3];
                var atk = enemies[4];

                var enemyTemplate = "<tr ><td colspan='2'><img src = './images/derpina.jpg' width ='200px'></td></tr><tr><td> Name</td><td>: " + name + "</td></tr><tr><td>Health Points</td><td>: " + life + " HP</td></tr><tr><td>Level</td><td>: " + lvl + "</td></tr><tr><td>Experiance</td><td>: " + xp + "</td></tr><tr><td>Attack</td><td>: " + atk;
                enemyspot.append(enemyTemplate);
                isCreated = 1;
            });
        }


    },

    validate: function() {
        var name = document.getElementById("name").value;

        App.contracts.Creation.deployed().then(function(instance) {
            alert("Your name is " + name);
            return instance.createhero(name, {
                from: App.account
            });
        }).then(function(result) {

            App.render();
        });
    },
    loadMonsters: function() {
        App.contracts.Creation.deployed().then(function(instance) {
            creationInstance = instance;
            return creationInstance.monsterCount();
        }).then(function(monsterCount) {
            console.log("äóöä" + monsterCount);
            for (var i = 0; i < monsterCount; i++) {

                creationInstance.enemies(i).then(function(enemies) {
                    App.enemies.push(enemies);

                });
            }
        })
    },

};
var enemyspot = $("#enemyspot");
let startFlag;
var account;
var accountInterval = setInterval(function() {
    // Check if account has changed
    if (web3.eth.accounts[0] !== account) {
        account = web3.eth.accounts[0];
        // Call some function to update the UI with the new account
        App.render();
        location.reload();
    }
}, 100);

function startAdventure() {
    $("#adventure").hide();
    var instructions = $("#advWrap");
    var heroT = "<p id='instructions'>Press W to walk <br> Press A to attack <br> Press R to run<p>";
    instructions.append(heroT);
   document.getElementById("#advWrap");
    startFlag = 1;
};
let isCreated;

console.log('fasdfas' + App.monsterId)
document.onkeyup = function(e) {
    if (e.which == 87 /*&& startFlag == 1*/ ) {
        console.log("iscreated is" + isCreated)
        let randomNum = Math.round(Math.random() * 3);
        console.log(randomNum)
        if (randomNum == 1) {

            if (isCreated == 0 || isCreated == null || isCreated == undefined  && App.heroes[1]>0) {
                alert("You have been ambushed!!!");
                App.spawn()
                isCreated =1;


            } else if (App.enemies[App.monsterId][1] <= 0  && App.heroes[1]>0) {

                App.spawn();
                isCreated =1;
            } else if (isCreated == 1) {
                alert("You must kill this monster first")
            }
        } else if(randomNum !== 1 && isCreated !==1) {
            alert("You didn't encounter any monster");
        }else if (isCreated == 1) {
                alert("You must kill this monster first")
            }
    }
    if (e.which == 65 && isCreated == 1 && App.enemies[App.monsterId][1] > 0 && App.heroes[1]>0) {
        console.log('123       ' + App.enemies[App.monsterId][1])

        App.fight()
    }
    if (e.which == 82 && isCreated == 1) {
         App.rand2 =Math.round(Math.random() * 1);
        if (App.rand2 == 0) {
            isCreated = 0;
            enemyspot.empty();
            App.rand2 = 1;
        } else if (App.rand2 ==1 ) {
            App.fight();

        }
    }
};

$(function() {
    $(window).load(function() {

        App.init();
    });
});
```

genesis file ...

```
{
"config":{
"chainId":15,
"homesteadBlock":0,
"eip155Block":0,
"eip158Block":0
},
"nonce":"0x0000000000000042",
"mixhash":"0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000",
"difficulty":"0x200",
"alloc": {},
"coinbase": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
"timestamp": "0x00",
"parentHash":"0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
000000000",
"gasLimit":"0xffffffff",
"alloc":{
}
}
}
```

Comment: Your code is formatted badly (comments are in wrong lines), it's not copypasteable (as each line includes > at the beginning) and you're not saying what you are trying to do when you get the error.

Comment: sorry i edit it

Comment: I cant find which function gives the error.. i get the error when  the metamask opens to do the first transaction. I bilieve the error comes from my contract code but i dont know where. I run the dapp with ganache and runs without problems

Comment: I have an error bigNumber Error: new BigNumber() not a base 16 number.
After search i saw the function getHerosByOwner causes this.. I try to solve it now. I deleted the func  but the error in metamask  (Transaction Error. Exception thrown in contract code)  still exists,

Comment: Do you configured your private network from a genesis `.json` file? If so, have you checked the `gaslimit` parameter of this file? Maybe you are running out of gas to make any transaction.

Comment: i checked that with an other dapp and can run again... so i think something with my genesis file is wrong iw ill edit it now.

Comment: Probably not the error but you have `alloc` defined twice. Obviously you need to define accounts with balance to make transactions or mine your ether creating a new account and setting as coinbase.

Comment: i have created an accounts and i have mine with it. I also connect the accounts with metamask

Answer (score 1):

I found it . Finally i had to let

```
App.web3Provider = new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('localhost:8545');
```

i putted instead of localhost  , the ip of my node . AND I change the version of solidity . Now i have 0.4.25.
 In the truffle config file add

compilers: {
    solc: {
      version: '0.4.25',
      optimizer: {
        enabled: true,
        runs: 200
      }
    }
  }